# Disabling username and password layer in RStudio proxy

Tags: authentication, rstudio, autologin

How can I disable the authentication for RStudio?

It is having by default log process of login prompt. I want to remove the login prompt and login directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible in the Community Edition of RStudio.

If you're using the Professional Edition, then you should refer here:

[Proxied Authentication](http://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/authenticating-users.html#proxied-authentication)

It says, you should change the following parameters under */etc/rstudio/rserver.conf*

```
auth-proxy=1
auth-proxy-sign-in-url=http://example.com/sign-in
```

The `auth-proxy-sign-in-url` should be your own authentication page or service which will be redirected from Rstudio server.

This `auth-proxy-sign-url` (after successful authentication) should then send a request with the following header back to the Rstudio server URL:

```
X-RStudio-Username: jsmith
```

Rstudio will use the header to recognize which user is trying to login to the server automatically.